# If stdout file get close where Data get saved or flushed

Tags: stdout

If we closed stdout file using close function and we print data using printf function where Data gets store are flushed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When stdout is closed, printf returns an error, and nothing is output (data is lost).

Excerpt from the printf man page:

> If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned.